# How can I log Kafka topic access

Tags: apache-kafka

from what I understand, Kafka has the schema of produce -> send data to topics, then consumer - get the data from those topics.

I will have many consumers (each on a different computer) on a single topic.

I would like to log each consumer's access to each topic so the log would look like this:

```
02-02-2022 IP:56.54.45.54 accessed topic "test topic" fragment 15
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has no such built-in mechanism

You would have to write/find an `Authorizer` implementation for this and configure that as an `authorizer.class.name` on the brokers

Two examples that I know of include

- Apache Ranger w/ auditting enabled
- OpenPolicyAgent w/ [decision logs](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/management-decision-logs/)

Comment: If you use Confluent Enterprise, then [you can enable Audit logs](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/security/audit-logs/audit-logs-concepts.html)